# Visual Composer text align

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a row on my page and have splitted it into two sections, 1/2 and 1/2.

On the one side is a picture and on the other side a text block. I want to vertically align the text block so that it is in the middle of the picture but I can't get it to work.

I tried to give the text block and the row a custom css with { vertical-align: middle;} but nothing changed.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: vertical-align: middle; only works in table display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

http://codepen.io/AxelCardinaels/pen/OVryrO
HTML :

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__image">
      <img class="image__img" src="http://i.imgur.com/rdXHVp7.jpg">
    </div>
     <div class="container__description">
       <p class="description__text">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis volutpat dui ac aliquam ultricies. Mauris nec dui lorem. Aenean finibus dictum erat id consectetur. Etiam auctor, libero eu tempor tincidunt, sapien mi cursus eros, quis viverra tortor neque sed lacus.
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container{
  display:table;
}

.container__description{
  width:50%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:2em;
}
```

Comment: @tymz96 You're welcome ! Don't forget to accept my answer then ! :)